# Twitter Bootstrap Not Displaying Correctly in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

Having major problems getting a twitter bootsrap site to be viewable in Internet Explorer.  http://warningweather.com/ is the site... below is a chrome thumbnail then an IE thumbnail and then the HTML code.  The navbar is appearing as a topdown list in Internet Explorer and the spans are appearing from top down in internet explorer.  I want it to look like it does in Chrome.

**Chrome Screenshot**
[image: Chrome Screenshot]

**Internet Explorer Screenshot**
[image: Internet Explorer Screenshot]

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Severe Weather Warnings - Torando Warning, Thunderstorm Warning</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet\ type="text/css">
    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=182733995114522";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://warningweather.com/tornado.gif"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Severe Weather Warnings - Torando Warning, Thunderstorm Warning"/>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://warningweather.com" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://warningweather.com"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Warning Weather"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="The Latest Weather Warnings from the National Weather Service"/>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="182733995114522" />
    <meta name="description" content="The Latest Weather Warnings from the National Weather Service " />


</head>
 <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".bs-docs-sidebar">
    <!-- Navbar
    ================================================== -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="brand" href="http://warningweather.com">Warning Weather</a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                         <ul class="nav"><li class="active">
                                    <a href="http://warningweather.com">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="http://warningweather.com/about/">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://warningweather.com/recent">Recent</a></li><li><a href="http://warningweather.com/blog">Announcements</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
        <center>
            <p class="hidden-phone">
            <script type="text/javascript"><!-- 
            google_ad_client = "ca-pub-5504765881600837"; 
            /* WarnWeather Top Banner */
            google_ad_slot = "0759690849";
            google_ad_width = 728;
            google_ad_height = 90;
            //-->
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
            </script></center></p>


      <div class="hero-unit">
        <h1>Warning of the Latest Weather...</h1>
        <p>With Warning Weather you can keep your readers and viewers in the know with weather warnings from the national weather service automatically being posted to your facebook page, twitter feed, and even website!</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="http://warningweather.com/customer">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>


<center><strong><a href="http://warningweather.com/day/September-24-2012">Warnings Today</a> | <a href="http://warningweather.com/day/September-23-2012">Warnings Yesterday</a></center></strong><BR />


      <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
          <h2>Recently Issued</h2>
<ul><li><strong><a href="http://warningweather.com/view/2012-KLZK-SV-W-0456@Severe-Thunderstorm-Warning">Severe Thunderstorm Warning for  Independence AR, Jackson AR, White AR, Woodruff AR,</a> </strong><BR><i>Expired: 2012-09-24 13:00:00 UTC</i></li><li><strong><a href="http://warningweather.com/view/2012-KCRP-SV-W-0146@Severe-Thunderstorm-Warning">Severe Thunderstorm Warning for  La Salle TX,</a> </strong><BR><i>Expired: 2012-09-24 02:00:00 UTC</i></li><li><strong><a href="http://warningweather.com/view/2012-KPHI-SV-W-0237@Severe-Thunderstorm-Warning">Severe Thunderstorm Warning for  Kent DE, New Castle DE, Cumberland NJ, Salem NJ,</a> </strong><BR><i>Expired: 2012-09-23 01:45:00 UTC</i></li><li><strong><a href="http://warningweather.com/view/2012-KPHI-SV-W-0236@Severe-Thunderstorm-Warning">Severe Thunderstorm Warning for  Burlington NJ, Camden NJ, Gloucester NJ, Bucks PA, Delaware PA, Philadelphia PA,</a> </strong><BR><i>Expired: 2012-09-23 00:45:00 UTC</i></li><li><strong><a href="http://warningweather.com/view/2012-KPBZ-SV-W-0208@Severe-Thunderstorm-Warning">Severe Thunderstorm Warning for  Allegheny PA, Armstrong PA, Butler PA, Westmoreland PA,</a> </strong><BR><i>Expired: 2012-09-23 00:00:00 UTC</i></li></ul>          <p><a class="btn" href="http://warningweather.com/recent">More Weather Warnings &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
          <h2>Currently Valid</h2>
                     <p>The National Weather Service currently has 0 currently valid severe thunderstorm warnings and 0 Tornado Warnings.  Keep your viewers safe, and engaged by automatically putting these warnings on your facebook page, twitter feed and website!</p>
           <p>If your viewers and readers know they can come to you for the latest Weather Warnings to keep themselves and their loved ones safe they will, they will stay engaged and coming back for more... its that easy!</p><p><strong>Great for Television Stations, Local Governments, Newspapers, Weather Related Siets, and more!</strong></p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
       </div>
        <div class="span4">
          <h2></h2>
          <script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-5504765881600837";
/* WarnWeather Big Square */
google_ad_slot = "8412928525";
google_ad_width = 336;
google_ad_height = 280;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
        </div>
      </div>
    <hr>

      <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2012 Zesty Labs; Warning Data by National Weather Service</p>
        <p><a href="http://warningweather.com/recent/tornado">Recent Thunderstorm Warnings Warnings</a> | <a href="http://warningweather.com/recent/thunderstorm">Recent Thunderstorm Warnings</a> | <a href="http://warningweather.com/recent">Recent Weather Warnings</a></p>
      </footer>

    </div> 
    <!-- Twitter Bootstrap Stuff -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-29669116-4']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

   <!-- Start of StatCounter Code for Default Guide -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var sc_project=7261892; 
var sc_invisible=1; 
var sc_security="d71e143e"; 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://www.statcounter.com/counter/counter.js"></script>
<noscript><div class="statcounter"><a title="tumblr hit
counter" href="http://statcounter.com/tumblr/"
target="_blank"><img class="statcounter"
src="http://c.statcounter.com/7535508/0/7df33614/1/"
alt="tumblr hit counter"></a></div></noscript>
<!-- End of StatCounter Code for Default Guide -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your site makes IE to get into quirks mode in IE.

1. You forgotten to close the "" marks for your second css links->  rel="stylesheet\
2. I'm guessing the second mistake is that you have meta tags after script and and css links. Try to change the orders for them, meta tags should be placed first.

Comment: In order to get into standards mode, you'll need a doctype see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Triggering_different_rendering_modes

Answer (score 1):

USe IE Developer tools.
I can see that a lot of js files that IE is searching for it cant find. I have attached a screenshot below showing 404 errors.

chrome/firefox renders the rest correctly leaving the missing files. IE however just breaks when it doesnt find some files and hence the messed up look on IE

[image]

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, while unrelated to the problem its helpful :)